# create an identifier for 2 variables

Tags: stata

I am fairly new at Stata and I need to create a variable that records the first instance of a combination of two variables (leader ID and year) and will allow it to hold the same value (1) for the duration of relationship. i.e. leader A's first year in power was 1973 and I need to carry that relationship over 138 dyadic observations of that leader's first year. Then the next year (2) and so on (3,4,5...). Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to give an example of what your data looks like and the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your leader identifier is stored in the variable `id`, a year variable is stored in `year`, multiple options are available.

Most simply:

```
egen idCombination = group(id year)
```

If you want the counter to reset for each separate leader (`group()` can not be combined with `by:`):

```
by id year, sort: generate newCombination = 1 if _n==1  
// takes value 1 for first time of combination, otherwise missing
by id (year), sort: generate idCombination = sum(newCombination)
```

Comment: `bysort id (year) : gen idCombination = sum(year != year[_n-1])`  is an alternative to the last.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your data look like, but I guess you want a new ID that contains the values of the original two variables. You may try this:

`egen newid = group(leaderID year), label`

The option `label` here labels the values of the two variables onto the new ID variable.

When you tab the new variable `newid`, you will see those values for each observation.

However, when you tab without label, i.e.,`tab newid,nol`, you will see that the new ID variable has actual values from 1~n, where n is your sample size.

Comment: There's no reason to suppose that the new identifier will get close to the sample size (i.e. number of observations). If you mean just that that's the upper limit, fair enough.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Theoretically, n should just be the upper limit.